# How can I return a list of records and true or false if a joined record exists using SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have three tables.

**Table A:**

TableA_ID, Description

**Table B:**

TableB_ID, TableA_ID, TableC_ID

**Table C:**

TableC_ID, Various Other columns

Table B may contain zero or more records linking a record from Table C to a record in table A

I want a query that will return ALL records from Table A and an additional column that will be True or False dependent on whether any related records exist in Table B for a specific TableC_ID value.

Any help mucho appreciated.

Cheers

Stewart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT a.TableA_ID, a.Description,
       CASE WHEN b.tableC_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END AS DoesExist
    FROM TableA a
        LEFT JOIN TableB b
            ON a.TableA_ID = b.TableA_ID
                AND b.TableC_ID = 123 -- Add your specific value here
```